# SASS Looping Selector

Tags: loops, include, sass, selector

I have got this repetitive selector as shown below:

```
// Level 1
.wrap > ul > li {
  background: green;
}

// Level 2 
.wrap > ul > li > ul > li {
  background: orange;
}

// Level 3 
.wrap > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  background: red;
}

// Level 4 
.wrap > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {
  background: light-red;
}

// Level 5 
.wrap > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li{
  background: salmon;
}
```

Is there a way I can create a sass function so I can just specify the depth and color like this

```
 **for example** 
 @include depth(5) { background: salmon })
```

I would appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`for`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_7) loop to generate the selector chain and then inject it into a rule with [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
@mixin depth($depth: 1) {
  $chain: '';
  @for $i from 0 to $depth {
    $chain: $chain + ' > ul > li';
  }

  & #{$chain} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

[example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7817003) | [gist](https://gist.github.com/rurjur/7817003)

Comment: You're freaking awesome. Thanks so much ;)